# Is it fine to remove docker images with repository name <None>?

Tags: linux, docker, operating-system

I am interested to know that is it fine to remove the docker images with repository name `none`? For example when I right `docker images` , I see images with name none as given below,

```
REPOSITORY         TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
seurat_tinga       latest    8948db3084b6   12 months ago   5.05GB
<none>             <none>    aa7e47099d4b   12 months ago   4.89GB
<none>             <none>    d8384ec762cf   12 months ago   4.89GB
<none>             <none>    d5f0cd78fd8d   12 months ago   4.89GB
rocker/tidyverse   4.0.3     7c4ecf0a0ce4   13 months ago   2.53GB
```

I remove all such images then there would be no effect on the working of the operating system or it would not break any dependencies of the operating system?

Thanks,

Comment: Your operating system doesn't depend on Docker containers. It's fine to delete them and all the rest of Docker's junk with `docker system prune`

Comment: Deleting images in general should be fine, since you can usually either `docker build` them from source or `docker pull` them from a registry.